# angular2 router 3.0.0 multiple levels

Tags: angular2-routing

Based on the latest Angular 2 Router (3.0.0-alpha.7) with the recent published documentation here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

I tried to add more levels of routing navigation without any success like this:

```
  export const CustomerRoutes: RouterConfig = [
  { 
    path: 'customer/:id',     
    component: CustomerComponent,   
    children: [
      {
        path: 'account', 
        component: CustomerAccountComponent,
        children: 
        [
          { path: 'info', component: CustomerInfoComponent },
          { path: 'billing', component: CustomerBillingComponent }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'idocs', 
        component: CustomerIDocsComponent,
        children: 
        [
          { path: 'ic', component: CustomerICComponent },
          { path: 'iprop', component: CustomerIPropComponent }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

But I get the error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'customer/123'

I want to have a customer detail page with two independent areas, which one has their *router-outlet* to load respective components without changing the content of the other router-outlet on same level and visible on page.

```
                     app                
                 /        \  
                /          \
          (...)         customer
                       /        \
                      /          \
             account (both visible) idocs
            /       \              /     \
         info    billing         iprop    ic
```

So I can navigate to levels like this:

```
/customer/123/account/info
/customer/123/account/billing
/customer/123/idocs/ic
/customer/123/idocs/ic/123
/customer/123/idocs/iprop
/customer/123/idocs/iprop/123
```

But when I am at customer page, I want to see the account and idocs section at both time.

Anyone knows how to achieve this? I have the plunker example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/TotsM3wv64u16GuUkoLF?p=preview